# Find the Differential equation $y=\sum_{i=1}^3 c_i e^{m_ix}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Finding the differential equation corresponding to
$$y=\sum_{i=1}^3 c_i e^{m_ix}$$ where $c_i$ are the arbitrary constants and $m_1,m_2,m_3$ are the roots of the equation $m^3-7m-1=0$

Comment: Using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients or http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/constantcof/constantcof.html, it should be $y'''-7y'-y=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how a few things connect here. First, what is the relationship between an ordinary differential equation, and its so-called characteristic equation?

> If the differential equation is $a_n y^{(n)} + \dots + a_1 y' + a_0 y = 0$, then the characteristic equation is $a_n m^n + \dots + a_1 m + a_0 = 0$. To see why this is, we guess $y = e^{mx}$, plug this guess into the differential equation, and then divide by $e^{mx}$ (since it is never zero, this is ok).

Secondly, how do the roots of the characteristic equation determine solutions to the differential equation?

> If $m$ is a root of the equation, then $e^{mx}$ is a solution of the differential equation.

Finally, there's the principle of superposition, which says that, if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of a linear, homogeneous equation, then $c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2$ is also. This extends in the obvious way to 3 (or more) solutions.

Thus, the answer is

> y''' - 7y' - y = 0